# Excel VB Code to Copy Multiple Ranges in Workbook, and Paste in new Workbook

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I am looking for a script that will copy a specific range of data, across multiple worksheets, and then paste that data into a brand new Workbook.  With my basic knowledge I can do this for a single worksheet in the workbook, but not multiple.

Example, copy cells A7:S1000 from Wkst A and then cells A7:S1000 from Wkst B.

Then paste those cells in a new workbook, on two new worksheets Wkst A and B.

I do not want to save the new workbook, and it must be a brand new workbook that is created each time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried? Please search around, especially on SO, as this question has been asked in many different forms.  Please show us what you've found and what has/hasn't worked, or any specific questions with some code you have.

Comment: I am currently using:

Worksheets("SheetName").Range ("A7:S1000").Copy
Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
    With newWB
        Set newS = newWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
        newS.Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone
        newS.Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        
    End With

I have tried to do an array for the Copy, but cannot get that to work for multiple ranges.  I also have not found anything that does not reference a new wb being saved, or a wb referenced beforehand.

Comment: (Can you instead kindly edit that code in to your OP and use the code tags (`{}`) to format it? Thanks!)

Comment: I want this, except for multiple worksheets and multiple ranges, without the save function

http://stackoverflow.com/a/35648489/7110600

Comment: You should search for "VBA loop through worksheets" and "VBA loop through ranges".  (PS: Please update your code into the OP, it's hard to read in the comments.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option, you would just pass your range to the DuplicateToNewWB procedure:

```
Public Function WorksheetExists(wbSource As Workbook, strWorksheet As String) As Boolean

    Dim intIndex As Integer

    On Error GoTo eHandle
    intIndex = Worksheets(strWorksheet).Index
    WorksheetExists = True
    Exit Function
eHandle:
    WorksheetExists = False
End Function


Public Sub DuplicateToNewWB(rngSource As Range)

    Dim wbTarget As Workbook    'The new workbook
    Dim rngItem As Range        'Used to loop the passed source range
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet   'The source worksheet in existing workbook to read
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet   'The worksheet in the new workbook to write

    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Add
    For Each rngItem In rngSource

        'Assign the source worksheet to that of the current range being copied
        Set wsSource = rngItem.Parent

        'Assign the target worksheet
        If WorksheetExists(wbSource:=wbTarget, strWorksheet:=wsSource.Name) Then
            Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets(wsSource.Name)
        Else
            Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets.Add
            wsTarget.Name = wsSource.Name
        End If

        'Copy the value
        wsTarget.Range(rngItem.Address) = rngItem
    Next

    'Cleanup
    Set rngItem = Nothing
    Set wsSource = Nothing
    Set wsTarget = Nothing
    Set wbTarget = Nothing
End Sub
```