# Copying a range into a new spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have found a solution for the basic part of this in this thread
[Copying range and pasting into new workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340688/copying-range-and-pasting-into-new-workbook)

However when I try to give it my range of

```
wsI.Range("A1:Q1500").Copy
```

> I am returned "Run-time error 1004".

Do I need to use some other method of copying the range?

For ease of use here is the full slightly edited code from the post I linked

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet

'~~> Source/Input Workbook
Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
'~~> Set the relevant sheet from where you want to copy
Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("SICAV")

'~~> Destination/Output Workbook
Set wbO = Workbooks.Add

With wbO
    '~~> Set the relevant sheet to where you want to paste
    Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~>. Save the file
    .SaveAs Filename:="Pictay.xls", FileFormat:=56

    '~~> Copy the range
    wsI.Range("A1:Q10").Copy

    '~~> Paste it in say Cell A1. Change as applicable
    wsO.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: the code you posted works just fine. What do you have "extra" in your code ?

Comment: The codes works fine for me too.

Comment: Hi, the code worked with the range "A1:Q10" but not with "A1:Q1500".

Comment: Can you try saving to `xlsx` and try again :)?

Comment: saving as xlsx worked, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Just saw your question and ran the code. It worked fine.
You must be intrigued by what caused the error in the first place. Some [research](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/210684/copying-worksheet-programmatically-causes-run-time-error-1004-in-excel) helped with this.

The very simple answer to it is that a problem like this may occur when you give the workbook a defined name and then copy the worksheet several times without first saving and/or closing the workbook.

for eg:-

```
For i = 1 To 10
   wsI.Range("A1:Q1500").Copy
   wsO.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
   SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Next i
```

Microsoft recommends, you save and close the workbook periodically while the copy process is occurring, as in the following sample code:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    wsI.Worksheets(i).Copy After:=wsO.Worksheets(i)        
    'Save, close, and reopen after every 100 iterations:
    If i Mod 100 = 0 Then
        wsO.Close SaveChanges:=True
        Set wsO = Nothing
        '' please change the path to your workbook below.
        Set wsO = Application.Workbooks.Open("c:\wsO.xls")
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Yes, Vityata. Thank you. FrasercT may need to decide if he'd like to abandon the programmatic approach in preference to the manual one.