# Filter Data copy that to new Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my Problem:
I'm trying to filter and copy data from WB1 then create WB2 and paste the filtered Data from WB1.

I googled now for quite some time and got code which kinda worked on their own but i can't get it to run when I try to combine them...

[Source1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340688/copying-range-and-pasting-into-new-workbook) [Source2](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-to-copy-paste-visible-cells-only.943868/)

here is my current code in which it gives me an

```
Runtime error 1004 - AutoFilter method of Range class failed
```

I'm really new in VBA and tbh I don't really know what else I could do now...

This is my current code and thx in advance :)

```
Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet

'Source WB
Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
'Quelltabelle
Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("Sheet1")
'Zieldatei
Set wbO = Workbooks.Add

    'OutputWB
    Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Sheet1")
    'Save new WB
    wbO.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\X\Y\NewFile.xlsx"
    'Filter & Copy the Data
    wsI.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="APL 1"
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1:CS" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    'Paste Date in new WB
    wsO.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    wbO.Save
```

Edit: Typo

Comment: Ah yes sorry this was my editing... 
ithe runtime error appears on the "wsI.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criterial:="APL 1" "row

Comment: Your sheet `wsI` isn't protected is it?

Comment: Also, the two lines after `Dim LR As Long` contain unqualified ranges - meaning Excel is left to guess what sheet the Range you're referring to is on. You need to prefix those (presumably) with `wsI.` - e.g. `LR = wsI.Range("A" & wsI.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Not tested but instead of filtering and copying, you could duplicate thr worksheet in a new workbook and delete all rows not containing `APL 1` in field 1

Comment: @CLR the thing is that, that part is working fine... 
When I skip the part of creating a new WB and only filter the Source WB and Copy the Values the code for that works...

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns that is quite a good Idea! I'll try it that way... 
Thank you!